# How to handle FormData AJAX post (file with additional params) with asp.net WebMethod

Tags: asp.net, jquery, asmx, webmethod, form-data

Having trouble handling a jQuery AJAX post of FormData to an ASP.net 4 Web service WebMethod.

```
<input id="ipt_file" type="file" />
<a href='#' onclick="UploadFile();" data-role='button'>Upload</a>
```

---

```
var UploadFile = function () {
    var file_object = $('#ipt_file')[0].files[0];
    var form_data = new FormData();
    form_data.append('job_id', '123456');
    form_data.append('job_name', 'xyx');
    form_data.append('job_file', file_object);

    var xhr_upload = $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        headers: { "Cache-Control":"no-cache", "Content-Type":"multipart/form-data" }, // also tried without these
        url: "../MyServices.asmx/Upload",
        data: form_data,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (msg) {
            if (typeof (msg) === "object") {
                var _upload = $.parseJSON(msg.d);
                alert(_upload.status + ': ' + _upload.msg);
            };
        }
    });
};
```

---

```
public class FileUploadRequest
{
    public string job_id { get; set; }
    public string job_name { get; set; }
    public HttpPostedFile job_file { get; set; }
}
```

---

```
[WebMethod]
public string Upload(FileUploadRequest x)
{
    string str_response = string.Empty;
    if (x.job_file.ContentLength > 0)
    {
        str_response = "{\"status\":1,\"msg\":\"" + x.job_id + ", " + x.job_name + ", " + x.job_file.FileName + "\"}";
    }
    else
    {
        str_response = "{\"status\":0,\"msg\":\"FAIL"\}";
    };
    return str_response;
}
```

---

Must not be handling the FormData object parameter properly; here I instantiated a custom class, but all I get back from the server is 500 errors (also tried a generic object x). Also tried handling it as HttpRequest object as I've seen on some postings, to no avail. Not concerned about IE 9 incompatibility in this case; just want to see single file upload or at least a FormData object with key/value pairs properly received by an asmx WebMethod.

Comment: Made some progress on this, but changed the service from asmx to svc: see question 18004679.

Answer (score 6):

I did get it to work with the following code, in case anyone wants to see it:

```
    var upload_file = $('#ipt_file')[0].files[0];
    var upload_filename = upload_file.name;
    var upload_maxsize = 10485760;
    var upload_projectname = "test";
    var form_data = new FormData();
    form_data.append('session_id', this.sessionID());
    form_data.append('project_name', upload_projectname);
    form_data.append('file_name', upload_filename);
    form_data.append('file_size', upload_file.size);
    form_data.append('file', upload_file);
    if (upload_file.size < upload_maxsize) {
    var xhr_upload = $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        headers: { 'Cache-Control': 'no-cache' },
        url: "../services/upload.ashx",
        data: form_data,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        dataType: "json"
        }
    })
    .done(function (xhr_data) {
        ...
    })
    .fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        ...
    })
    .always(function () {
        ...
    });
```

Comment: Are you still using the same WebMethod as in your original question?  If not, can you post the contents of upload.ashx?

Comment: Thanks, reminds me of what I ended up doing.   We use a base class for membership management, so we just ended up using an aspx file for this.  I did steal a few tricks from your file, though, cheers!

Comment: No problem - glad it helped - I recall the whole exercise was kind of a pain ;)

Comment: I know this is bit old thread but how does your ashx.cs file look like. The link does have anything.

Comment: Would love if you could post the working code behind as well @brnwdrng

Answer (score 5):

.NET will not allow the **multipart/form-data** for the content-type:

[JSON Hijacking and How ASP.NET AJAX 1.0 Avoids these Attacks](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/json-hijacking-and-how-asp-net-ajax-1-0-mitigates-these-attacks)

> There is a built-in validation layer of protection that ASP.NET
>   enforces for both GET and POST based ASP.NET AJAX web methods, which
>   is that regardless of the HTTP verb being used, A**SP.NET always
>   requires that the HTTP Content-Type header is set to the value
>   application/json**. It this content type header is not sent, ASP.NET
>   AJAX will reject the request on the server.

Comment: Wow, this is exactly the reason that I'm having a problem, and I haven't been able to find this documented anywhere. Thank you.